# What All Should I do If I find a deadlock occurring in SQL server 2012? Are there a set of rules/steps I can follow to come out of it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I identified a couple of Update statements on a Large Partitioned table as Deadlock victims from extended events. How should I proceed with Fixing this?

This table doesn't have an Index. We are using UniqueIdentifier (RefGuid) in where clause of both these Update statements. SQL server Execution plan is suggesting to create a non clustered index on this column. Will this prevent/Alleviate Deadlocks?

Thanks In Advance.

Solution that alleviated Deadlocks in my case.
Created a Non clustered Index on the column being checked in where Clause. The column being used in Partition function was not used in where clause and hence was not useful.

Comment: Which isolation level, u are using?

Comment: No Isolation level around these update statements. I am sure almost all Selects on this table should have NOLOCK

Comment: Ok then, as SQL server Execution plan is suggesting, creating a non clustered index on the column suggested, will help to scan table faster or u can look for increasing timeout also.

Comment: A good discussion to refer, http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1247696-391-1.aspx

Comment: Sure, Will try creating Index and monitor if locking still occurs. However I am not sure if this will Prevent deadlocks.

What I am looking at is tips that may alleviate DeadLocks.

Comment: Did you try a Google "sql prevent deadlocks"   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191242%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: My favorite resources for tracking down deadlocks are: 

* http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/deadlock-troubleshooting_2c00_-part-1.aspx for some basics.
* Detecting and Ending Deadlocks at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178104.aspx
* Trace Flag 1222 Doc at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the deadlocks are just because there are update and select statements to the same table at the same time, you should first focus on getting both the update and select statements to touch as small amount of pages as possible. Easy way to get started is to run the statements using "set statistics io on" and see the number of logical reads (or writes, which is usually a lot smaller). The lower you get the I/O, the less likely it is that a deadlock will happen.

If there's several different columns in the where clause, you should try to focus on the column(s) that have the highest selectivity, meaning the ones that there's the least amount of rows per value. It might be useful to have more than one field in the index, but that of course depends on your data and the SQL statements. Looking at the actual execution plan is also a good idea, but remember that the percentages there are just estimates.

Since your table is partitioned, make sure that always when possible, you have also included the key used for partitioning in the where clause. Like always, it is also essential that the data types match (column vs search criteria). You can see the number of partitions accessed in the actual plan (properties of the object).

If your process is more complex and there's a lot of updates into different tables inside the transactions, if possible, try to always make the updates to the tables in the same order.